# How to Write NFC Tags only from My Android App

Tags: android, nfc

I am newbie to NFC Android App Development. I am developing an App that should be capable of Writing different types of NFC Tags. I am done with writing all types of Tags.

But my problem is that client is asking to restrict the users to write the tags from another android apps once the tags were written from My App. I have searched in google and read documentation of android developer guide but failed to find any result. Is there any way to restrict users to write the tags from only one app. If yes, will it work for all types of Tags. I hope MifareClassic can be restricted from writing tags from other apps as we can do authentication by using custom key. Does such kind of implementation there for other cards too?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your exact needs. In some cases, an NFC tag can be made read-only. This would prevent anyone from writing to the tag. In other cases, such as MIFARE, a form of access control is possible (exactly as you describe), where authentication is needed to get access to writing functionality. It depends on the specific NFC tag whether it supports this. Often the exact details on how to do this is are only available under NDA. So I would suggest you contact your supplier for details on the tags that you intend to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can I have list of tags that can be locked with password protection or else all the tags can be made password protection?

Comment: Tags I am familiar with that allow this are MIFARE Ultralight C and DESFire. The [recently announced](http://www.nxp.com/news/press-releases/2012/10/nxp-enables-mass-market-adoption-of-nfc-tag-applications.html) new NTAG21x series offer password protection, too.